# Extracting the scale component of a transform matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to break break a transform matrix into translation-rotation (together) and scale components in Eigen.

The [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1463487/243832) explains the math.

I can easily extract the translation and rotation components with the `rotation()` and `translation()` methods but I couldn't find a direct way to get the scaling component.

The best way I managed to do it is this:

```
void DecomposeTransform(const Eigen::Matrix4f& transform)
{
    Eigen::Affine3f affineTransform{transform};
    Eigen::Affine3f rotation{affineTransform.rotation()};
    Eigen::Affine3f translation{Eigen::Translation3f(affineTransform.translation())};
    Eigen::Affine3f translationRotation{translation * rotation};

    float Sx = transform.block<3, 1>(0, 0).norm();
    float Sy = transform.block<3, 1>(0, 1).norm();
    float Sz = transform.block<3, 1>(0, 2).norm();

    Eigen::Affine3f scale{Eigen::Scaling(Sx, Sy, Sz)};
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It's not too bad, but I was wondering if there a method or perhaps a more elegant way to extract the scale component as well...?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have rotation, then maybe you can solve the last equation in [your link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati/1463487#1463487) for Sx, Sy, Sz

Comment: I think that would only make the solution slightly longer... :s

Comment: I think the scaling would be the diagonal elements of ( inv(transform) x rotation), however indeed your implementation is better on the eye